# Why I have to do `eval` and `ssh-add` every time I switch projects?

Tags: macos, ssh, git, gitlab

I do have in my `~/.ssh/config` file two different GitLab accounts. Both are named on `Host` different and refers on `Hostname` to `gitlab.com`.

Every time I switch between coding projects of the different GitLab accounts, I have to do:

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/<ssh-key-for-GitLab-account-of-actual-project
```

I've read here [What eval and ssh-agent commands do?](https://superuser.com/questions/1356026/what-eval-and-ssh-agent-commands-do), that it has something to do with Docker, but in my case it's only on my local machine.

Is there a way, avoiding insert this two commands all the time?

Comment: https://medium.com/uncaught-exception/setting-up-multiple-gitlab-accounts-82b70e88c437

Comment: Maybe this will shed some light on the issue: https://rabexc.org/posts/pitfalls-of-ssh-agents

Comment: How do you switch between the projects?

Comment: ..I've not forgotten you <3 I'll try your solutions on the weekend - both are very interesting!!
I switch between the projects sometimes in iTerm2 (a Mac terminal emulator), sometimes with JetBrains PhpStorm IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the way @JavIon has provided:
https://medium.com/uncaught-exception/setting-up-multiple-gitlab-accounts-82b70e88c437

On my system, I've done some fine tuning.

1st step:
Go into your local directories where you use Git. In my case, I use Git with GitLab.
In my work directory are some git repositories and some regular files and directories - same in my private directory.
I've created in each of these directories a .gitignore file.

Work:

```
#------------------------------------------#
#         .gitconfig GitLab Work           #
#------------------------------------------#


[user]
    name     = My name for commits at work
    email    = email@work.com
    username = Work GitLab username
```

Private:

```
#------------------------------------------#
#        .gitconfig GitLab Private         #
#------------------------------------------#


[user]
    name     = My name for commits at private
    email    = email@private.com
    username = Private GitLab username
```

2nd step:
Go into your home directory and open .gitconfig (if there is none, create one).
Then include the .gitconfig files from your directories, except that in home directory.

~/.gitconfig:

```
#-----------------------------------#
#        .gitconfig Global          #
#-----------------------------------#


#----------------- Work GitLab
[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
    path = ~/work/.gitconfig


#----------------- Private GitLab
[includeIf "gitdir:/~/private/"]
    path = ~/private/.gitconfig
```

3rd step:
Go into your local Git repositories and add in all of them the specific SSH key.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/<your key>
```

For me, that has worked without logout or reboot.